# How to get location wise tweets using tweepy for streaming API?

Tags: twitter, tweepy

I am trying to pull all the tweets from San Francisco containing federer. I am getting error with the locations keyword.

```
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream
import csv
access_token = ''
access_secret = ''
consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''
csvfile = open('StreamSearch.csv','a')
csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter = ',')


class StdOutListener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        print data
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print status


if __name__ == '__main__':
    l = StdOutListener()
    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)
    stream = Stream(auth, l)
    stream.filter(track='federer',locations = '-122.75,36.8,-121.75,37.8')
    #stream.filter(track='djokovic')
```

The error is

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "C:\EclipseWorkspaces\csse120\9sept\src\SearchTweets.py", line 35, in <module>
    stream.filter(track='federer',locations = '-122.75,36.8,-121.75,37.8')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line 307, in filter
    raise TweepError("Wrong number of locations points, "
tweepy.error.TweepError: Wrong number of locations points, it has to be a multiple of 4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is good until the stream.Filter phase. The filter queries are taken as lists by Tweepy not as individual strings.

So if you wanted to find everything with Federer you would search for

```
stream.Filter ( track = ['federer'])
```

And for the location you would use

```
stream.Filter ( locations = [-122.75,36.8,-121.75,37.8] )
```

Keep in mind that locations are not strings and do not need quotes on them. Also Twitter uses the JSON format for locations that are Longtitude, Latitude which is different than the typical Latitude, Longtitude coordinates given by Google Maps and other services.

Unfortunately you will not be able to track tweets that contain Federer from San Francisco as when you have a location and track filter it becomes a track OR locations query. That means you will get tweets that either contain Federer or are from San Francisco. I don't know of a way where you can do AND queries for various filters. I don't believe Twitter supports them. Your options are to collect Tweets from San Fran and then see if any mention Federer or Federer tweets and then filter them by location. You still can concatenate location and track but it will be an OR query for those two and would look like this:

```
stream.Filter ( track = ['Federer'], locations = [-122.75,36.8,-121.75,37.8] )
```

The documentation for Tweepy and the Twitter parameters are available at
https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview/request-parameters
http://tweepy.readthedocs.org/en/v2.3.0/api.html?highlight=location

Hope this helped.

Comment: how can I find the four parameter location points for Madison, Wisconsin? I only knew of latitude and longitude

Comment: @MonaJalal, two corners have to contain both a lat, long. So the first two numbers are one point of the bounding box and the other two lat,long define the other point of the bounding box. Hope that makes sense!